# Installed library using checkinstall which created a package named "python" and causes dependency issues

Tags: python, dpkg, checkinstall

I wanted to try out the new major version of a c++ library called gtsam. Since I'm currently using an older version of the library for several projects and I wasn't sure about dependency issues, I decided to install it using checkinstall:

```
mkdir build && cd build
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Since it came with a python wrapper which I also wanted to install, I did:

```
cd python
sudo checkinstall python setup.py install
```

Now I wanted to remove the version again, so I checked under which package name the library was installed.

The main library was called "build" which I already found strange, although I could remove it using:

```
sudo dkpg -r build
```

When I now tried to do the same with:

```
sudo dpkg -r python
```

it complained about dependency problems because it's interpreting "python" as the main ubuntu python package.

If I do `dpkg -l python` I get:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                          Version                     Architecture                Description
 +++-=============================================-===========================-===========================-==================================================
ri  python                                        20160629-1                  amd64                       Python part of gtsam-4.0.0-alpha1.
```

At this point I'm actually a little bit scared and don't know what to do, to fix this issue. I want to uninstall the files installed by `checkinstall python setup.py install` without screwing up the configuration of my system python setup.

I actually used checkinstall because I did *not* want to worry about reverting the installation...

Comment: Note : Checkinstall cannot be used to create a python-module package.

Comment: @KnudLarsen I stumbled upon some block entry [link](http://remind-nix.blogspot.de/2010/08/using-checkinstall-tool-with-python.html) that recommends the usage of checkinstall with python and also other people seem to be using the tool for python packages...I understood the main thing checkinstall does is recording a history of file copies done by some install procedure, so it can be reverted. Am I wrong with that assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I think I solved the problem.

I found out that with `apt-cache showpkg python` I can view all the different python versions available. I picked the latest one and installed it using:

```
sudo apt-get install python=2.7.5-5ubuntu3
```

It gave me a warning it couldn't delete some "old directories":

```
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/usr/local/lib/python2.7': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/usr/local/lib': Directory not empty
dpkg: warning: unable to delete old directory '/usr/local': Directory not empty
```

But that's fine, since I actually tried to solve the problem *without* deleting these directories.

Now if I do a `dpkg -l python` I get the following, correct output:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                          Version                     Architecture                Description
+++-=============================================-===========================-===========================-====================================================================
ii  python                                        2.7.5-5ubuntu3              amd64                       interactive high-level object-oriented language (default version)
```

I will monitor if I get any more strange behaviour from my system, but for now it seems this fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked for me. The key line in the output is: 
`The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:  python`